# how to change string _id to mongoid to delete record from mongo database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

this doesn't delete the record from the database

collection.delete_one({"_id": ObjectId("574acf1e7af7b6073c2cf9ae")});

Answer (score 0):

db.collection.deleteOne( { "_id" : ObjectId("574acf1e7af7b6073c2cf9ae") } );

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, 
there was an error is 
undefined method `ObjectId' for #<ApplicationController:0x0000000a2563e0>
Did you mean?  object_id